# Why is my variable resetting its value?

Tags: powershell

Below is a powershell script I'm attempting to write. The problem is when I call the Validate-Response method, the variables $playGame and $validResponse keep resetting their value even though inside the method Validate-Response is clearly saying to set them both to true if the user inputs "Y". Help?

**The method that is being referred to is:**

```
function Validate-Response{
    $validResponse
    if ($response -eq "Y"){
        $validResponse = "True"     
        $playGame = "True"
    } 
    elseif ($response -eq "N") { 
        Clear-Host 
        Write-host " `n`n Please return and play again soon." 
        Read-Host exit
        break 
    } 
    else { 
        Clear-Host
        Write-Host "`n`n Invalid input. Please press Enter try again." 
        Read-Host
           $validResponse = "False"

    }
    return $validResponse, $playGame
}
```

**The Entire program:**

```
#Define variables used in this script 
$playGame 
#Controls gameplay and when to stop gameplay 
$response = "" 
#Stores the player’s input when prompted to play a game 
$number = 0 
#Stores the game’s randomly generated number 
$secretWord = "" 
#Stores the secret word for the current round of play 
$attempts = 0 
#Keeps track of the number of valid guesses made 
$status = "True" 
#Controls the current round of play 
$guesses = "" 
#Stores a list of letters by the player during gameplay 
$reply 
#Stores player letter guesses 
$tempstring 
#Stores a display string, with hidden characters, that is used 
#to represent the secret word during gameplay 
$validReply 
#Stores the player’s response when prompted to play a new game
$validResponse
#String listing unacceptable input 
$GuessesRemaining 
#Keeps track of the number of guesses the player has left 
#Create an Associative array and load it with words 
$words = @{} 
$words[0] = @("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "") 
$words[1] = @("C", "O", "M", "M", "A", "N", "D", "E", "R") 
$words[2] = @("F", "L", "A", "G") 
$words[3] = @("T", "O", "A", "S", "T", "E", "R") 
$words[4] = @("M", "A", "R", "K", "E", "R") 
$words[5] = @("P", "I", "C", "T", "U", "R", "E") 
$words[6] = @("D", "E", "S", "K") 
$words[7] = @("G", "L", "O", "B", "E") 
$words[8] = @("S", "P", "E", "A", "K", "E", "R") 
$words[9] = @("B", "A", "C", "K", "Y", "A", "R", "D") 
$words[10] = @("P", "E", "N", "C", "I", "L")

#This function determines if the player’s guess is correct or incorrect 
function Check-Answer { 
    param ($reply) #Argument containing the player’s guess 
    #Access script-level variable representing valid users guesses and 
    #add the current guess to it 
    $script:guesses = $script:guesses + " " + $reply 
    #Loop through each letter in the secret word (e.g., each element in the
    #array) and see if it matches the player’s guess 
    for ($i = 0; $i -le $secretWord.length - 1; $i++) { 
        if ($secretWord[$i] -ne $reply) { 
            #The guess does not match 
            #Place an underscore character into $word[0] in place of the letter 
            if ($words[0][$i] -eq "") {$words[0][$i] = "_"} 
        } 
        else 
        { #The guess matches #Place the letter being guessed into $word[0] 
            $words[0][$i] = $reply 
        } 
    } 
}
function Validate-Answer{
    param ($reply)
    $validReply = "False"
    if ($reply -eq "") { 
        #If an empty string was submitted, repeat the loop
        continue  
    } 
    #It is time to validate player input 
    elseif ($reply.Length -gt 1) { 
        #Limit input to one character at a time 
        Clear-Host #Clear the Windows command console screen 
        Write-Host "`n`n Error: You may enter only one letter at a time." 
        Read-Host "`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n Press Enter to continue." 
        $reply = "" #Clear out the player’s input
        continue # Repeat the loop 
    } 
    elseif (1234567890 –match $reply) { 
        #Numeric input is not allowed 
        Clear-Host #Clear the Windows command console screen 
        Write-Host "`n`n Error: Numeric guesses are not allowed." 
        Read-Host "`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n Press Enter to continue." 
        $reply = "" #Clear out the player’s input 
        continue #Repeat the loop 
    }
    elseif ($rejectList -match $reply) { 
        Clear-Host #Clear the Windows command console screen 
        Write-Host "`n`n Error: Special characters are not permitted." 
        Read-Host "`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n Press Enter to continue." 
        $reply = "" #Clear out the player’s input 
        continue #Repeat the loop 
    }
    else{
        $validReply = "True"

    }   

}



#Prompt the player to guess a number 
while ($playGame -ne "True") {
    Clear-Host 
    #Clear the Windows command console screen 

    #Display the game’s opening screen 
    Write-Host "`n`n`n`n" 
    write-Host " Welcome to the                         *********" 
    Write-Host "                                        *       *" 
    Write-host " PowerShell Hangman Game!               O       *" 
    Write-host "                                      __|__     *" 
    Write-host "                                        |       *" 
    Write-host "                                       / \      *" 
    Write-host "                                                *" 
    Write-host "                                                *"
    Write-host "                                                *" 
    Write-host "                                             *******" 
    #Collect the player’s guess
    while ($validResponse -eq "False"){
    $response = Read-Host "`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n Would you like to play? (Y/N)"
    Validate-Response $reponse
}



}
#Prompt the player to guess a number 
while ($status -eq "True") {
    #Reset variables at the beginning of each new round of play 
    $tempString = "" 
    $words[0] = @("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "") 
    $attempts = 0 
    $guesses = "" 
    $reply = "" 
    #Generate a random number between 1 and 10 
    $number = Get-Random -minimum 1 -maximum 11 
    $secretWord = $words[$number] 
    #Populate an array with the letters that 
    #make up the game’s secret word using the 
    #random number to specify the array index
    #Create a loop to collect and analyze player input 
    while ($validReply -eq "False") {
        Clear-Host #Clear the Windows command console scre              
        $reply = Read-Host "`n`n Enter a guess" #Collect the player answeren 
        Validate-Answer $reply
        Clear-Host #Clear the Windows command console screen 
        $attempts++ #Only increment for good guesses

        #Now that player input has been validated, call on the Check-Answer #function to process the input 
        Check-Answer $reply 
        $tempString = "" #Clear out this variable used to display the current state of the word being guessed 
        #Loop through $words[0] and create a temporary display string that 
        #shows the state of the word being guessed 
        for ($i = 0; $i -le $words[0].length - 1; $i++) { 
            $tempString = $tempString + " " + $words[0][$i] 
        }
        #Display the current state of the secret word based on the input 
        #collected from the player 
        Write-Host "`n`n Results:`n" 
        Write-Host " ----------------------------------------- -`n" 
        Write-Host " $tempString`n" 
        Write-Host " ------------------------------------------`n`n" 
        Write-Host " Letters that have been guessed: $guesses`n" 
        #Calculate the number of guesses that the player has left 
        $GuessesRemaining = (12 - $attempts) 
        #Display the number of guesses remaining in the current round of play 
        Write-Host " Number of guesses remaining: $GuessesRemaining"
        #Pause the game to allow the player to review the game’s status 
        Read-Host "`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n Press Enter to continue" 
        if ($tempString -notmatch "_") { 
            Write-Host "`n Game over. You have guessed the secret word!" ` "in $attempts guesses.`n`n" 
            Write-Host " The secret word was $secretWord `n`n" 
            Write-Host "`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n" ` "`n`n`n`n`n`n`n" 
            Read-Host #Pause gameplay 
            $reply = "Done" #Signal the end of the current round of play 
            break #Repeat the loop 
        } #The player is only allowed 12 guesses, after which the game ends 
        if ($attempts -eq 12) {
            Clear-Host Write-Host "`n Game over. You have exceeded the maximum allowed" ` "number of guesses.`n`n" 
            Write-Host " The secret word was $secretWord `n`n" 
            Write-Host " The best you could do was $tempString`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n" ` "`n`n`n`n`n`n`n" 
            Read-Host #Pause the game 
            $reply = "Done" #signal the end of the current round of play 
            break #Repeat the loop 
        }


        $reply = "" #Clear out the player’s input
    }

    $response = "" #Reset value to allow the loop to continue iterating 
    #It is time to prompt the player to play another round 
    $validReply = "False" #Set variable to ready its use in the while loop 
    #Loop until valid input is received 
    while ($validReply -ne "True") {
        Clear-Host #Clear the Windows command console screen 
        #Prompt the player to play a new game 
        $response = Read-Host "`n`n Play again? (Y/N)" 
        #Validate the player’s input 
        #Keep playing 
        if ($response -eq "Y"){
            $validReply = "True" 
            $status = "True" 
        } 
        elseif ($response -eq "N") { #Time to quit 
            Clear-Host #Clear the Windows command console screen 
            Write-host " `n`n Please return and play again soon." 
            Read-Host #Pause gameplay 
            $validReply = "True" 
            $status = "False" 
        } 
        else { #Invalid input received 
            Clear-Host #Clear the Windows command console screen 
            Write-Host "`n`n Invalid input. Please press Enter to try again." 
            $validReply = "False" 
            Read-Host #Pause gameplay 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of posting 500 lines of some unclear code try posting [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `Validate-Response` takes no input and your `$playGame` and `$validResponse` variables are not global.
Either pass these variables into your function(s) or make them global.

### EDIT

Here are some links to help you with functions and variables:
[Functions](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/functions.html)
[Create Your Own PowerShell Functions](http://windowsitpro.com/windows/create-your-own-powershell-functions)
[How Scopes Affect PowerShell Scripts](http://www.howtogeek.com/203778/how-scopes-affect-powershell-scripts/)

```
$global:varName
function funcName($arg) { 
    <script block> 
}
```

Comment: How would you go about passing the variables into function? param($validResponse, $playGame)?

Comment: @BrandonGandy you might wanna start by looking into how to write functions in general. 
[Functions](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/functions.html) and 
[Create Your Own PowerShell Functions](http://windowsitpro.com/windows/create-your-own-powershell-functions)

Comment: I'll look into but how do you make a variable global?